# Is there a way to redefine a function from within another function in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to port a game to python and there is one thing that I can't figure out how to do. The game functions on a system where the buttons you can press modify a variable with their button number and call a function to determine what to do next. This function is redefined by any function that needs to take button input and called after the button is pressed. It works like this.

```
class Mainclass
{
  function buttonEventN() : void #function called when buttonN is pressed
  {
    this.buttonChoice = N;
    this.function();
  }
  function event() : void
  {
    #code for game event
    this.function = function() : void #define what to do after the buttons are pressed
    {
      #determine what button was pressed and continue
    }
  }
}
```

This is a simplified version of what is going on but it shows the exact same thing. The game event event() is called first, it defines the function function() and then finishes. The game doesn't do anything while waiting for a button press.

I tried taking everything out of the main class and using global statements for everything, which isn't ideal, and it worked but is there another way to do this without taking everything out of the main class?

Comment: There's two ways this question could be answered, 1) how to emulate the way language X does thing Y in Python, and 2) how to directly do Y idiomatically in Python. Which type of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Guys, read the first sentence: "trying to port a game to python" This look like the original code the OP is trying to port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.button_choice = None
        self.function = None

    def button_event_n(self, N): 
        self.button_choice = N
        if self.function:
            self.function()

    def event(self): # code for game event
        def function():
            print(f"Button {self.button_choice} was pressed") # determine what button was pressed and continue
        self.function = function
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I don't know why I didn't think to do it that way but it works.

Comment: @AlexanderDelguidice Perfect, then if you can accept this answer so the question is closed

Answer (score 0):

Python classes and their instances are dynamic and their methods can be reassigned. When you call a method like `foo.bar()`, python will first attempt to resolve "bar" on the instance and then fall back to the class definition. Assign a "bar" method and you will get the new function call for just that one instance.

I wrote this example as a method type, but you can also do this with a static method if the function doesn't need access to the instance variables. If "baz" is already a method on this class, you wouldn't need the `MethodType` part.

```
from types import MethodType

class Foo:

    def bar(self):
        print("bar", self)

    def event(self):
        self.bar = MethodType(baz, self)


def baz(self):
    print("baz", self)

f1 = Foo()
f1.bar()
f1.event()
f1.bar()

f2 = Foo()
f2.bar()
f2.event()
f2.bar()
```

Output